# 100% width with variation on html page

Tags: html, css

I have a page that I want to have 100% full width, but when I use the 100vh command, I'll see the following:
Used Code : height:100hv;
http://s8.picofile.com/file/8312677942/100hv.png
And when I do not use any command, I'll face this problem:
Used Code : height:auto;
http://s8.picofile.com/file/8312677968/auto.png
When I do not use any code and the number of elements is high, there will be no problem
Used Code : height:auto;
http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312677918/good.png
But I do not have this problem when the element is too low on the page. If there is a solution, please guide me.

Comment: Please share code to get best possible answer. Btw, you can use `width: 100vw` to make an element as wide as viewport width.

Comment: I've used a lot of files on the page, such as javascript and css, so it's difficult for me to put the code.
No, I mean, I tested the program with your code, and I saw that when the files are low, it works fine, which is not possible with my code. Now the number of fields that goes up again finds the 100hv problem.

Answer (score 1):

it's 100vh and not 100hv. And I suppose that you want the full "height" of your window, not the full width.

**EDIT**

You have to put that in your css :

```
height: auto;
max-height: 100vh;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: If you mean the code, I've tested this code and this is a problem for me, and if this is not yours, please use the code to use it. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's not 100hv, it's 100vh, the last two letters are inversed

Comment: I do not know if it is possible for me to have a Java programming language when the number of elements is too high for example 7 to be of an automatic width and when the number of elements is less than 7, its width is 100. ??

Comment: It's javascript, not java, and you don't need to do it on javascript, you can use max-with or max-height property. I really don't know why you talk about width, I think that your problem is about height.
I posted in answer, under EDIT, the properties you need in your css